# Placeholder text is not vertically centered in Safari

Tags: javascript, css, html

Do you have any idea on how to get the placeholder attribute to vertically center in safari? 
Though when you start typing, the text is perfectly centred.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

-Safari Solution-

I got stuck on this issue for a long time despite using

`input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     line-height:normal!important;
}`

It turns out that having a line-height in the immediate `input` element was breaking my `input::webkit-input-placeholder` line-height.

**Solution extended:**

I removed the line-height in my input style and it fixed my issue.

Comment: Best answer...!

Comment: This `-webkit-input-placeholder` thing also fixes cropping placeholder text in safari, e.g. bottom part of letter "g"

Comment: This also works for Mozilla issues. `::-moz-placeholder `

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way is to use both the `line-height` and `height` CSS properties. Just give the text input a `line-height` with the same value as its `height`.

By the way, your live site looks okay to me in chrome 16.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

For me the best solution is to use line-height:normal and hack for IE 8.

```
<input type="text" name="test_name" placeholder="Search">


input {
    height: 35px;
    line-height: normal;
    line-height: 32px\0/; /* for IE 8 */
}
```

Comment: Amazing!  This is the only solution I've found (with only height and line-height) that works on both IE8 and Safari.

Answer (score 7):

Had this bug too. Setting line-height in ems fixed this for me. It looks the same in Chrome, Safari(desktop and iOS) and Firefox. and I added a \9 trick to get vertical centering in IE. here's my css

```
height: 36px;       
line-height: 1.2em;
line-height: 26px\9; /*for IE */
```

Answer (score 5):

Works fine for me:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Search" style="height: 50px;">
```

[image]

Try changing this:

```
#register-block-fields input {
width: 230px;
height: 41px;
padding-left: 40px;
padding-right: 20px;
height: 41px; // Changed from line-height
color: #878787;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background: none;
}
```

Comment: I usually find it's best to use both height and line-height for text inputs. IIRC gecko does something weird otherwise. Apparently in some cases webkit does as well.

Comment: That's usually what I go with too. Also make sure to use this method in other fields, for some reason I got a different page in safari to chrome so I used this as an example.

Comment: This is perfect! Removing line-height will mess up IE though. I kept it there but just added /9 after it which seems to fix that.

Comment: yeah, playing around with CSS is usually required when you're covering 5 different browsers :)

Answer (score 2):

For me this worked well:

```
line-height: inherit;
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me, maybe because my input element is inside a flex box.

I ended up needing to specify a line-height in px - with a large value for the line-height compared with the default for input elements.

```
input[type="text"] { line-height: 32px; }
```

Feels like a hack, but it's the only thing I could get to work.