# Placeholder is not vertical aligned

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, sitefinity

I used bootstrap but placeholder is not in center align 
[image: Find My OPTIFAST Clinic OPTIFAST.png]

```
<input id="findNearestClinicText" type="text" placeholder="ENTER YOUR ZIP CODE">
```

Inputbox font size is : 20px
Placeholder font size is: 14px

my client doesn't want to change the font size of the input box and placeholder. but if I set it with the same font size then it aligned center.

I want the placeholder to be aligned the center of the text box with a different font size of textbox and placeholder. Please help.

Comment: its due to line-height. Try to play with line-height.

Comment: Use the same line-height.

Comment: Could you just turn up the brightness of your screen, a little? It's a bit difficult to see the code you've *already tried*...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placeholder text is not vertically centered in Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323596/placeholder-text-is-not-vertically-centered-in-safari)

Comment: i also update my answer . plz check it

Answer (score 1):

use ::placeholder class in css

css

```
#findNearestClinicText{
width: 400px;
font-size: 20px;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
 text-align:center;
 font-size: 14px;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
   text-align:center;
   font-size: 14px;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
   text-align:center;
   font-size: 14px;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   text-align:center;
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

Please check this link https://jsfiddle.net/xunbfvvh/

Answer (score 0):

**using Padding In css**

**Method-1** : ***using id***

```css
#findNearestClinicText
{
  padding:10px;
  font-size:20px;/* Inputbox font size*/
}

/* Placeholder font size is: 14px */    
   #findNearestClinicText::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
   font-size: 14px;
 }
#findNearestClinicText::-moz-placeholder { 
  font-size: 14px;
 }
#findNearestClinicText::-ms-input-placeholder { 
  font-size: 14px;
 }
#findNearestClinicText::-moz-placeholder { 
 font-size: 14px;
 }
```

```html
<input id="findNearestClinicText" type="text" placeholder="ENTER YOUR ZIP CODE">
```

**Method-2 :** ***Using Attribute***

```css
input[type='text']
{
  padding:10px;
   font-size:20px;/* Inputbox font size*/
}
/* Placeholder font size is: 14px */

   input[type='text']::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
   font-size: 14px;
 }
   input[type='text']::-moz-placeholder { 
  font-size: 14px;
 }
input[type='text']::-ms-input-placeholder { 
  font-size: 14px;
 }
input[type='text']::-moz-placeholder { 
 font-size: 14px;
 }
```

```html
<input id="findNearestClinicText" type="text" placeholder="ENTER YOUR ZIP CODE">
```

Comment: It has been made with the same placeholder and input font size. We need 14px font size in placeholder and 20px font size in input (When user types, it should be 20px font size).